# How to filter and sort the array based on the most relevant values?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Suppose I have an array which is in the below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => playstation sony 3 slim 320gb
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => sony xperia acro s
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => sony xperia tipo
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => sony ericsson xperia arc s
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => sony xperia go
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => sony playstation 4
        )

)
```

Now I want to filter the array based on the search value and sort the array by the based on **most relevant** (by shortest length).

My request data is:

```
 $request = 'sony';
```

I'm expecting the following results:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => sony xperia go
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => sony xperia tipo
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => sony playstation 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => sony xperia sony acro ss
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => sony ericsson xperia arc s
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => playstation Sony 3 slim 320gb
        )

)
```

Comment: _How it is possible in PHP_ - Yes, it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: BTW, you have declared an array with the same keys.

Comment: @Federico i do not know how to call that function does this !!! i have search for t, but did not get any result how to do that, can i get at least some advice which way i should do that

Comment: Iterate over the array, and search every value with `substr_count`.

Comment: @Federico thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: 'whichever matches most' - by what criteria?

Comment: Try filter array by [`array_filter`](http://uk3.php.net/array_filter) then sort it by [`usort`](http://uk3.php.net/usort).

Comment: @kenorb thanks a lot, but when i try the array_filter i get only one documents back , can u kindly give me a example !

Comment: @ChristoferHansen Not sure what do you mean by one document, but click on the link, scroll down and you'll see plenty of examples there.

Comment: @ChristoferHansen I think your code example is wrong, as normally in PHP array you can't have the same keys, so you tried to simplify it, but your question further confuse people. So I can't provide example against invalid example. And you should define the criteria of most matches. Then explain what it has to do with the documents. A proper valid example would be useful.

Comment: @kenorb i actually need to check which element of the array is more relavant with the request, and sort the array based on the relavant

Comment: @ChristoferHansen Define 'relavant', having an exact match and being the shortest? Or having the most matches, or starting from the beginning? Maybe based on some external relevance ratio value? Or some other criteria?

Comment: @kenorb i have update my question, is it more clear now !!!

Comment: @ChristoferHansen Looks better, however the 'most relevant' is broad and ambiguous (Google is working on 'most relevant' results for many years), so you need to further define your sorting criteria, because all rows contain `sony`, so how do you know which one is the most relevant for you? Can you give some expected result of such search and which one is the most relevant and why? Or this is the list after your performed search (basically the result)?

Comment: @kenorb yes i will explain it in my question

Comment: @kenorb i have update my question

Comment: @ChristoferHansen How to use global variable in lambda function, you need a separate question for that, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve your search filtering in PHP is to filter array ([`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/array_filter)) by your custom callback then sort it using a user-defined comparison function ([`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)).

Here is a simple code:

```
<?php 
$data[]['name'] = 'foo';
$data[]['name'] = 'playstation sony 3 slim 320gb';
$data[]['name'] = 'sony xperia acro s';
$data[]['name'] = 'sony xperia tipo';
$data[]['name'] = 'sony ericsson xperia arc s';
$data[]['name'] = 'sony xperia go';
$data[]['name'] = 'sony playstation 4';
$data[]['name'] = 'bar';

$result = array_filter($data, function($v) { return stristr(current($v), 'sony'); });
usort($result, function($a, $b) { return strlen(current($a)) < strlen(current($b)) ? -1 : 1; });
print_r($result);
```

Please note that PHP is not a good solution for implementation of complex search requirements. So for more search-oriented solutions, please consider using:

- [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)
- [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch)

which can be easily integrated with PHP.